# In Qt, what are the different ways to set an environment variable and what are the pros & cons?

Tags: qt, environment-variables

Specifically:

- **What are all the different ways I can set an environment variable?** *I know about `qputenv`. What about `qmake` and the `.pro` file? What about Qt Creator build settings? What about commands like `QGuiApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);`? Are there other ways too? Please include any restrictions (e.g. `qputenv` must be used before instantiating the `QApplication` within `main.cpp`)*
- **What are the pros and cons of each approach?**
- **For each approach, can you give an example setting the variable to:**

  - an integer
  - a string
  - another environment variable

Answer (score 3):

There's a lot of confusion here... qmake and pro files can set environment variables for the compilation process, `qputenv` for the application itself (and its children).

`setAttribute` isn't even about environment variables - it's about some particular settings of the `QGuiApplication`.

Given that they affect completely different things, there's no way to talk about pros and cons - we are comparing apples to oranges.

As for setting environment variables to particular types, that's a question without much meaning - environment variables are just a dictionary of strings. If you want to set it to an integer, you'll have to convert it to a string first with whatever Qt/C/C++ method you prefer. As for the `setAttribute`, again it's a completely different thing, it just manipulates flags, so talking about setting a string or an integer has no meaning here.

Comment: You said that if it needs to be an integer (e.g. `QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_HOVER_ENABLED` must be set to 0 or 1 according to Qt docs) then we should use a string. So, strictly the docs should have said "0" or "1". Is that correct?

Comment: Could you explain the difference between an environment variable for qmake & pro vs. application. I've seen no differentiation in the Qt docs. And specifically, could I set, say, QT_QUICK_CONTROLS_HOVER_ENABLED within the .pro instead of setting it in qputenv. If so, what's the right syntax?

Comment: Environment variables set in the `.pro` file affect just the compilation, not the execution of the program. They are present while you compile (so, for example, they are visible to the compiler), not to the program itself that you'll later run.

Comment: About the 0 or 1: meh, whatever; given that environment variables can only be strings, generally you don't even put double quotes around values in documentation, since there's no ambiguity.